# Operations at backend or at front end?

Tags: javascript, optimization, web-applications, distribution, backend

In routine SPA development, there are operations which takes few milliseconds. Now, as servers/backend are more powerful, should we perform such operation on backend and send processed data to clients or we should take advantage of distribution and off load this processing to clients?

e.g. If a process takes 100ms and we expect 5k hits

- Server will require 5k * 100ms = 9 minutes roughly and increased memory
  while
- Client may take 300ms on each device which may not be
  substantial.

Question here is, how to decide what to process at backend and what to distribute and divide to devices?

Comment: let the clients do everything - then your server got nothing to do and you can use it to play the newest computergames in ultra quality.

Comment: I think you can look at queuing mechanisms like rabithq, that might help you address some of this processing tasks

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend use back-end if there are operation on secure data.
If not - use front-end, because:

1. As you mentioned, it's additional load to server and server time
2. If there is high load, then additionally to previous problem you also will have clogging channel of unneeded requests.

If you can do something without back-end - do it.